# Zahlwörter für »1,5«

Tags: prefix, numbers

Ich kenne nur

> - *sesqui*  und
> - *anderthalb*

- Gibt es weitere Zahlwörter für *1,5*?
- Gibt es eine Verallgemeinerung für andere nicht-Ganzzahlen, die größer als *1* sind?

Comment: "sesqui" ist kein Deutsch.

Comment: @Em1 Gibt es denn ein deutscheres Präfix? Im [mathematischen Bereich](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitesche_Sesquilinearform) scheint es mir, ganz gut akzeptiert zu sein. Warum soll es kein Deutsch sein?

Comment: "Hermitesche Sesquilinearform"? Wtf!?- Ja, in der Mathematik werden so einige Begriffe verwendet, die nicht unbedingt "Deutsch" sind. Sesqui verstehen also nur Mathematiker. Wenn überhaupt. Das Wort "hermitische" ist offensichtlich auch kein deutsches Wort, ist es ja nur von so nem Typen abgeleitet. Damit ein Wort zum deutschen Wortschatz gehört, gehört einiges mehr, als in irgendeinem Mathematikbuch Erwähnung zu finden.

Comment: @Em1 Das Präfix *sesqui* wird nicht nur in mathematischen Zusammenhängen und nicht nur in ein paar Texten erwähnt: Chemie und Musik nutzen das auch. Es ist eher das Präfix für *1,5*, genau wie *bi-*, *zweimal-* oder *doppelt-* Präfixe für *2* sind. Dass es nicht gewöhnlich ist, dass die Zahl  1 ½ nicht so oft auftritt, ist anders. Aber damit es *kein Deutsch* sei, würde ich sagen, du solltest ein Gegenbeispiel finden, wo stattdessen anderes Präfix benutzt wird.  Es muss so ein Präfix geben, oder?

Comment: In dem Punkt kannst du mir getrost vertrauen. *Sesqui* ist ein **lateinisches Präfix**, das in einigen Fachtermini Verwendung findet. Wer Latein kann oder eben jene Fachbegriffe kennt, wird dich verstehen. 95% der Deutschen verstehen das aber nicht! Du wirst es wahrscheinlich in einem Fremdwörterlexikon finden. Und nein, die deutsche Sprache hat meines Wissens nach **kein entsprechendes Präfix**. Ich wüsste auch nicht, wofür man es braucht. Apart: *Eineinhalb* und *anderthalb* sind übrigens Zahlwörter.

Comment: *Bi-* ist übrigens auch ein lateinisches Präfix, was im Deutschen ausschließlich in aus dem lateinischen übernommenen Wörtern existiert. In rein germanischen Wörter findest du das Präfix nicht. *Bi-* ist aber im Gegensatz zu *sesqui-* weitläufig verstanden, nicht zuletzt, da wir hömmele an Wörtern mit *bi-* übernommen haben. *Bizeps*, *Bisexualität* um nur zwei Beispiele zu nennen. Wörter mit *sesqui-* gibt es keine. Daher kann man streiten, ob *bi-* eingedeutscht ist, oder nicht. Aber *sesqui-* ist es definitiv nicht.

Comment: Dreihalbe kann man noch sagen oder 15 mal 10 hoch -1 oder 1500 Milli~.

Comment: @Em1 natürlich ist *bi-* ein lateinisches Präfix. Aber *Nummer*, *Mensa*, usw. sind auch ursprünglich Latein, sind eingedeutsch und benutzt im Alltag. Was ist das Problem mit *sesqui*? Dass es nicht so häufig auftaucht? Es taucht bestimmt öfter als "Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz" auf. Trotztdem hat niemand Probleme, um das letzte Wort als echtes Deutsch anzuerkennen.

Comment: Dich mag noch der canoo.net-Artikel zu [Adjektivableitung: Fremde Präfixe](http://www.canoo.net/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/Praefixe-F/Praefixe-F.html?MenuId=WordFormationRules1118) interessieren. Dort ist zwar beispielsweise *bi-* aufgezählt, jedoch nicht *sesqui-*. Zahlwörter (wie hier in deiner Frage) fallen unter die Kategorie Adjektive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich kenne und nutze noch `eineinhalb` (ein-ein-halb) oder mehr im Dialekt `ein-ä-halb`.

Im Netz fand ich auch [ein-an-halb](https://www.google.de/search?q=ein-an-halb).

Zu dem Thema gab es anscheinend schon eine Untersuchung: [Die Geschichte der deutschen halb-Zahlwörter : Untersuchungen zur Neubesetzung eines lexikalischen Feldes und zur Univerbierung syntaktischer Gruppen](http://d-nb.info/978529987)

Comment: Ein-ä-halb und ein-an-halb wird aber nie geschrieben.

Comment: Ja, ein-ä-halb war der Versuch ein Wort im Dialekt wiederzugeben. Ein-an-halb ist mir persönlich unbekannt, kann also gut sein, das es nur ein Dialektausdruck aus einer mir nicht bekannten Gegend ist.

Comment: Wo ich herkomme spricht man so, aber man schreibt eineinhalb. Als Alternative zu anderen Wörtern würde ich prinzipiell keine Vorschläge aus Mundarten machen, außer es wird explizit danach gefragt.

Answer (score 4):

Ich wage zu behaupten, dass *anderthalb* und *eineinhalb* die einzigen standardsprachlichen Variationen sind, um 1 ½ in einem Wort auszudrücken. Für die Zahlen 2 ½, 3 ½ etc. gibt es nur eine Möglichkeit: zweieinhalb, dreieinhalb, ...

Das von Knut erwähnte *einanhalb* entspricht *eineinhalb* und basiert auf regionaler Aussprache.

Natürlich gibt es noch *eins Komma fünf*, *zwei Komma fünf* und so weiter. Findet aber außerhalb der Mathematik wenig Anwendung. Wenn ich auf dem Markt 1 ½ Kilo Erdbeeren kaufen möchte, würde ich immer *anderthalb* oder *eineinhalb* sagen, äußerst selten aber *eins Komma fünf*.

Das gilt auch für *eineinviertel*. Theoretisch auch für *eineinachtel*, wobei je kleiner die Zahl wird, desto unwahrscheinlich, dass sie gebraucht wird.

Anders sieht es bei Zahlen wie 1,3 oder 2,6 aus. Während *eindreizehntel* oder *zweisechszehntel* durchaus richtig wären, wird hier doch meist *eins Komma drei* und *zwei Komma sechs* bevorzugt.

Comment: a) Zwoeinhalb, b) Je nach Maßeinheit wechselt man bei 1,3 dann oft auf die kleinere Einheit, also von 1,3 kg auf 1300 Gramm. c) `je kleiner die Zahl` kann man aber nicht sagen - 1,6 ist ja größer als 1,5.

Comment: @userunknown Jo, wenn ma zweenenhalf oder vielleich ooch dreenhalf killo kopt, oder wenn man die *drei* eindeutig von der *zwo* unterscheiden möchte, **dann** haben wir natürlich noch mehr Möglichkeiten. - Und mit "je kleiner" habe ich mich natürlich auf "eineinsechzehntel", "eineinzehntel", "eineinzwölftel" und so bezogen. Nicht von Ungefähr steht unmittelbar zuvor "eineinviertel" und "eineinachtel".

Comment: Ja, aber "einneunzehntel" ist auch größer als "eineinzehntel" u.v.a. "eineinhalb" und dennoch sagen wir es nicht.

Comment: +1, aber ich würde Dir sogar sesqui Punkte geben, wenn ich könnte, da ich auch deine Kommentare zu diesem Thema sehr gut finde.